# Google Drive API. Get id from url

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, google-drive-api

I need move a drive file between folders using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and PHP. But in some case I only have the url of the document, and I need to move that file to another folder. But I don't know if is possible to do this having only the file url.

Any body know if its possible and how? I'm looking for it in the documentation but I can't do it.

Thanks.

Comment: its not it apparently used to be but there's a bug in the API. You will have to download it and upload it to the new directory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can "move" the file like that. The only way it might work would be to try and patch the location of the file  file.patch.  I have never heard of anyone trying to patch the location of a file.

I consulted a colleague who is a Google Drive expert, he said he thought it was broken (patching location). He did a quick test and verified this is a broken feature. All it returns is 403 - insufficient permissions

You will need to download the file and upload it again.

Comment: What kind of format I need to can upload again the same type of file?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the documentation page for patch (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) and it looks like Google has silently changed the API. There are now two new query parameters `addParents` and `removeParents` which look like they will do what you want. NB I haven't tested this as it has only appeared in the last couple of weeks.